# nvd3: deactivate moving of a brush?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3s lineWithFocusChart in a project. My customer wants to be able to resize the range of the brushes by using the start and end toggles, but the feature of "move the brush range" by dragging is not desired. My first attempt was to make the event handler return false if a move is detected:

```
chart.focus.dispatch.on( "brush.start", function( evt ) {
                if ( d3.event.mode === "move" ) {
                    console.log( "Aborting move operation" );
                    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                    d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log( "Ok" );
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

This doesn't work - while I can cleary distinguish between a move and a resize, returning from the event handler still allows both operations. I think the code in my event handler is executed afterwards.

I would like to refrain from changing the original source of the library since it's included via npm and would break any update machanisms and new installations of the project on other systems.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this pretty easily with just css:

```
/*Only permit resize */
/*Remove ability to drag/ double-click focus */
    .nv-brush>.background{
        display:none;
    } 
/*Remove ability to move focus */
    .nv-brush>.extent{
        display:none;
    }
```

If you wanted to remove the resize and only leave the ability to move the focus:

```
/*Only permit move */
/*Remove ability to drag/ double-click focus */
    .nv-brush>.background{
        display:none;
    }
/*Remove ability to resize focus*/
    g.resize{
        display:none;
    }
```